# Why the same Android App isn't compatible between Android 7.0 and further?

Tags: java, android

I'm coding an Android App and use an SimpleAdapter to display an ArrayList. Why the same App doesn't work on Android 8.0 and further ?

Actually, i have developed an application which is using a ArrayList of event and it's working on my personal phone (Android 7.0), I have test it on Android 5.1 and it work too. My problem is it doesn't work on Android 8.0 and further.

This is my tree :

```
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── java
│   └── inkara
└── res
    ├── drawable
    ├── drawable-v24
    ├── layout
    ├── layout-v26
    ├── mipmap-anydpi-v26
    ├── mipmap-hdpi
    ├── mipmap-mdpi
    ├── mipmap-xhdpi
    ├── mipmap-xxhdpi
    ├── mipmap-xxxhdpi
    ├── raw
    └── values

15 directories, 1 file
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listmsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listmsg = findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    }

    public void showItems(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems) {
        String[] name = {"name", "info"};
        SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, listItem, R.layout.list_perso,
                name, new int[]{R.id.Name, R.id.Info});
        listmsg.setAdapter(mSchedule);
    }
}
```

Then, here's my XML files :
**list_perso.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="65px"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="50px" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_convention"
        style="@style/myList"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="651dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

So, on Android 7.0 and less it work great, but on Android 8.0 and further we get this report :

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{inkara.inkara/inkara.inkara.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at inkara.inkara.MainActivity.afficherListeConventions(MainActivity.java:56)
    at inkara.inkara.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7210)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7201)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Share you xml, my guess is you are using something in the xml that is not working correctly on your recycler view or listview as the listMsg is null. Put a breakpoint before set adapter, you can see that the list from the xml was probably not found which would lead me to believe that some xml element is not compatible.

Comment: You may be using different layout resources for different versions.  Do you have multiple layout directory, such as layout-v36, layout-en etc.

Comment: @Sam i just update with two XML files.

Comment: @fthdgn yes i actually a layout-v24, is that a problem ?

Comment: yes, if you use specific layouts (layout-v24) you need to add one as a backup one for version not compatible with v24 in the layout folder

Comment: @ClémentVétillard Both activity_main.xml should have a ListView with id "mylist". Or you can delete layout-24 and alwasy use same xml.

Comment: Yup, you left the v-26 folder up there so it's finding the wrong layout. Simply remove the v-# folders unless you intentionally build files for those directories to have various views for later versions. An example would be if you are using a new UI element that was not available prior to v26. You may use one type of UI element in normal layout and then use your fancier new xml ui element layout in the v26 folder. So that's your issue. You have to have the same activity_main.xml in both folders if you did this on purpose and both must have the listMsg xml name listView in them or delete v26.

Comment: Also noticed you named it list_convention in the main_activity but you refer to it with  findViewById(R.id.mylist) in the code. That is also an issue

Comment: Yes my program was wrote in French  I just translate it too fast... Sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple versions of activity_main.xml on different "layout-*" directories, all versions should have same views with same ids.

If your all xml's are should be same, then delete all except the one on the "layout" directory.

If you don't know what the layout-v24 is, you can read this guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources